¿Como puedo saber o ver el error de una web desde mi consola?
Que parte mismo puedo ingresar para ver los errores de una página que queiro programar. Para ver si esta funcionando.

Depende del navegador, por lo menos en Chrome y en Edge se hacen presionando F12 y luego la pestaña consola

te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

conoces la herramienta de desarrolladores de los navegadores???

si alguna de las respuesta te ha servido podes marcarla como resuelta, eso te dara al menos 2 puntos de reputacion que te seran utiles en un futuro. saludos.

Para desarrollar hay diferentes herramientas para realizar el debug de páginas web dependiendo de la tecnología el entorno de desarrollo siempre tendrá un apartado para el debug.
Ahora todos los navegadores tienen una sección para desarrollo, en esta sección podrás ver varias pestañas, las más comunes (DevTool): Elementos, Consola, Red, Rendimiento, Memoria, Aplicación, Seguridad, etc. (Varia segun Navegador)
Estas herramientas te ayudara a ver errores en el frontend y algunos indicios de errores de en backend así como errores de políticas de seguridad en la red y/o peticiones.
Dejare un resumen por aqui de como acceder a estas en diferentes Entornos:
Google Chrome:

Haz clic derecho en cualquier parte de la página y selecciona "Inspeccionar" o presiona Ctrl+Shift+I en Windows/Linux o Cmd+Opt+I en macOS.
También puedes acceder a través del menú: haz clic en los tres puntos en la esquina superior derecha, luego en "Más herramientas" y selecciona "Herramientas de desarrollador".

Mozilla Firefox:

Haz clic derecho en cualquier parte de la página y selecciona "Inspeccionar elemento" o presiona Ctrl+Shift+C en Windows/Linux o Cmd+Opt+C en macOS.
Alternativamente, puedes ir al menú haciendo clic en las tres líneas en la esquina superior derecha, luego en "Desarrollador" y selecciona "Herramientas de desarrollo".

Microsoft Edge:

Haz clic derecho en cualquier parte de la página y selecciona "Inspeccionar elemento" o presiona Ctrl+Shift+I en Windows/Linux o Cmd+Opt+I en macOS.
Otra opción es hacer clic en los tres puntos en la esquina superior derecha, ir a "Más herramientas" y seleccionar "Herramientas de desarrollador".

Safari (macOS):

Primero, habilita las herramientas de desarrollador en las preferencias de Safari. Ve a Safari > Preferencias > Avanzado y marca la casilla "Mostrar menú Desarrollo en la barra de menús".
Luego, haz clic en "Desarrollo" en la barra de menú y elige "Mostrar inspector web".

Nota: es normal que un desarrollador tenga mas de una herramienta para hacer debug.
Vista de la herramienta de desarrollador para Google Chrome en Windows 11:

